# Submit and cancel buttons are not working, as well as the popup will cause the collapsible panel to close. How do we solve this issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tried testing functions on the submit and cancel buttons but the functions do not seem to be called.
When I press either 'submit' or 'cancel' buttons, they cause the form to close, as well as the modal panel to close. I am trying to make those button close only the form while keeping the modal panel to open.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var item = ''
  $('.show').click(function() {
    item = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '') //get the value
    var target = item + 'zxc'

    if (document.getElementById(item).className == 'panel-collapse collapse') {
      document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'grid';
    } else if (document.getElementById(item).className == 'panel-collapse collapse in') {
      document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'none';
    }
  });

  $('.ricedish').click(function() {
    target = $(this).attr('id') + 'zxc' //get target id
    //alert(target); 
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = "flex";
  });

  $('#btncancel').click(function() {
    canceltarget = $(this).parentNode().attr('id') //get parent node
    alert(canceltarget)
  });
});
```

```css
/* for the forms */

{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Button used to open the contact form - fixed at the bottom of the page */

.open-button {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 23px;
  right: 28px;
  width: 280px;
}


/* The popup form - hidden by default */

.form-popup {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  top: -100%;
  z-index: 9;
}


/* Add styles to the form container */

.form-container {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid red;
}


/* Set a style for the submit/login button */

.form-container .btn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}


/* Add a red background color to the cancel button */

.form-container .cancel {
  background-color: red;
}


/* Add some hover effects to buttons */

.form-container .btn:hover,
.open-button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='menu'>
  <h1 id='menutitle'><a style='color:red' href='index.html'>Back </a> <br>Menu items </h1>
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#ricedishes" class='show'>
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            Rice Dishes (Additional toppings can be chosen)
          </h4>
        </div>
      </a>

      <div id="ricedishes" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body" id='ricedisheszxc'>

          <div class='ricedish' id='chickenrice'>

            <div class='pic'></div>
            <h4 align='center'>Chicken Rice<br> $3.00</h4>

            <div class="form-popup" id="chickenricezxc">
              <!-- form -->
              <form class="form-container">
                <h1 style='margin:0;'>Chicken Rice $3.00</h1>
                <h3>Choose the type of chicken:</h3>
                <hr>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Roasted<br>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Steamed<br>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Chicken Cutlet
                <hr>
                <h3> Extra toppings ($0.50 each)</h3><br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="egg">Egg<br>
                <input type="checkbox" value="chicken">More Chicken<br><br>
                <hr> Remarks:
                <br> <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="remarks"></textarea><br><br><br>

                <button class="btn submit" id='btnsubmit' onClick='submit()'>Submit</button>
                <button class="btn cancel" id='btncancel'>Cancel</button>
              </form>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get to run your code properly, but your main problem is that you have mixed up javascript and jquery. In jquery we don't have parentNode() function. instead, we have parent(). Always look at the console to understand your javascript bugs.

```
$('#btncancel').click(function(){
   canceltarget = $(this).parent("form").attr('id') //get parent node
   alert(canceltarget)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use jQuery when you have it.

Something like this

```js
$(function() {
  $('.show').on("click",function() {
    var panelID = $(this).attr('href'); //get the target
    var $panel = $(panelID);
    var $target = $(panelID + 'zxc');
    $target.css({"display":$panel.is(".in")?'grid':'none'});
    $panel.toggleClass("in")
  });

  $('.ricedish').on("click",function() {
    $($(this).attr('id') + 'zxc') //get target id
      .css({"display":"flex"});
  });

  $('#btncancel').on("click",function() {
    canceltarget = $(this).closest(".panel-body").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
/* for the forms */

{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Button used to open the contact form - fixed at the bottom of the page */

.open-button {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 23px;
  right: 28px;
  width: 280px;
}


/* The popup form - hidden by default */

.form-popup {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  top: -100%;
  z-index: 9;
}


/* Add styles to the form container */

.form-container {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid red;
}


/* Set a style for the submit/login button */

.form-container .btn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}


/* Add a red background color to the cancel button */

.form-container .cancel {
  background-color: red;
}


/* Add some hover effects to buttons */

.form-container .btn:hover,
.open-button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='menu'>
  <h1 id='menutitle'><a style='color:red' href='index.html'>Back </a> <br>Menu items </h1>
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#ricedishes" class='show'>
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            Rice Dishes (Additional toppings can be chosen)
          </h4>
        </div>
      </a>

      <div id="ricedishes" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body" id='ricedisheszxc'>

          <div class='ricedish' id='chickenrice'>

            <div class='pic'></div>
            <h4 align='center'>Chicken Rice<br> $3.00</h4>

            <div class="form-popup" id="chickenricezxc">
              <!-- form -->
              <form class="form-container">
                <h1 style='margin:0;'>Chicken Rice $3.00</h1>
                <h3>Choose the type of chicken:</h3>
                <hr>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Roasted<br>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Steamed<br>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Chicken Cutlet
                <hr>
                <h3> Extra toppings ($0.50 each)</h3><br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="egg">Egg<br>
                <input type="checkbox" value="chicken">More Chicken<br><br>
                <hr> Remarks:
                <br> <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="remarks"></textarea><br><br><br>

                <button class="btn submit" id='btnsubmit' onClick='submit()'>Submit</button>
                <button class="btn cancel" id='btncancel'>Cancel</button>
              </form>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```